# I want to get the part of words from whole word

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I want to get the part of words from whole word.

If I search the word  `apples`

I need result of `App,Apple,Apples`

Some time if we enter the word 'apple'

it will give the result of (App,Apple,Apples)

```
SELECT * FROM pwyju_pin_tag WHERE pin_tag_words LIKE "%Apples"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If** you need to search for all words begin with `App`

just use `%` after `App` in your query

```
SELECT * FROM pwyju_pin_tag WHERE pin_tag_words LIKE "App%"
```

**If** you need to search for all words contain `App`

then use `%` before `App` and after it in your query

```
SELECT * FROM pwyju_pin_tag WHERE pin_tag_words LIKE "%App%"
```

Comment: And hope that 'Application' isn't in `pwyju_pin_tag`, or that would be desired to come back

Answer (score 2):

Just switch the operands around:

```
SELECT * FROM pwyju_pin_tag WHERE 'apples' LIKE CONCAT(LOWER(pin_tag_words), '%')
```

Comment: It give correct result when enter word like 'Apples'
But
 if we enter the 'apple' not give the records having apples..

Comment: @AnnaiMahalingam Added handling for mixed cases to my answer, take a look.

Comment: Thanks, its working for me. But its give the result all alphabets Like (apples,apple,app,ap,a)one by one i don't want like that
just search by first three or four letters...

Answer (score 0):

```
declare  @search nvarchar(24) ;   
set @search='apples';

 SELECT * FROM pwyju_pin_tag WHERE pin_tag_words 
  LIKE CONCAT(SUBSTRING ( @search ,0, x ),'%')
```

x is parameter where you can set it in every value you want (considering it is <`@search.length`)

In this case (where you want 'app') you must set `x=3`

Comment: Im only give the word like  apples